# Sound card is no longer recognised.

Tags: sound

ever since I installed Ubuntu on to my computer, the sound card has not been recognised and therefore no sound. I have tried the on board sound card with the same result. The sound card I am using is the "Sound Blaster Z - SB1500". The mother board is the "Asus P8Z77 Series".
Can anyone point me in the right direction?
Ian

Answer (score 0):

It may be a problem of drivers not installed. Try using the program 'Additional driver' that is pre-installed to download the appropriate drivers. If it doesn't work, try to download them manually from the producer's site.